# Unit Tests are not appearing in Test Explorer VS 2015 Enterprise Edition

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I have set Test Settings - x64 & cleared temp folder in %temp% still no result

-- I Do have vs 2013 in same machine, where it shows test cases in Test explorer but not on vs-2015

I do have installed Nunit Test Adapter as well as Nunit 3 Test Adapter In Extensions & Updates.

Please let me know what could be the fix any one

Comment: Thanks, got resolved by doing repair vs2015, from appwiz.cpl

Answer (score 1):

Having had three developers and 5 PC's with this problem all is better now.

a) vs2015 update 2 b) Removed all files from the TFS workspace - Get specific version 1, followed by manual file delete. c) Opened the solution from TFS to get latest required files

Happy at last

p.s. We run with Admin privileges as IIS debugging is required.